# Odd behaviour of SELECT on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I observed this skipping rows for this type of expression quite a few times and always wondered whether this is a bug or if it makes sense - at least technically. The purpose of the queries is to generate sequential table content. Mostly DATEs or DATETIMEs.

`t` is just any table with at least 30 rows.

This version produces the result as intended:

```
set @date = "2012-01-01";

select
    @date := date_add(@date, interval 1 day) as d
from t
#having d < "2012-01-31"
limit 30
;
```

output:

```
'2012-01-02'
'2012-01-03'
'2012-01-04'
...
'2012-01-31'
```

now including the HAVING condition (so I don't have to use a number to limit how many rows I want to generate, but can simply specify an upper boudary):

```
set @date = "2012-01-01";

select
    @date := date_add(@date, interval 1 day) as d
from t
having d < "2012-01-31"
limit 30
;
```

output:

```
'2012-01-03'
'2012-01-05'
'2012-01-07'
...
'2012-01-29'
'2012-01-31'
```

But please mind - this is a WHY-question - not a HOW-question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `HAVING` without an aggregate function, nor does it make sense to use `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause. Sets are by definition unordered and you do not know what order will be returned.

Comment: with all due respect, sir, but you are wrong. try to understand the purpose of the queries and then you understand why I use limit and having while not using aggregate functions or grouping.

Comment: While it is syntaxically correct, it is the source of your error. I'll post an answer explaining why.

Comment: Oh that would be splendid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call the column `d` in your `HAVING` clause, it computes the expression `@date := date_add(@date, interval 1 day)` again. This means that `interval 1 day` is added **twice** to the initial `@date` variable, thus why you have gaps in your entries. You can verify this fact by adding an extra condition, for instance `HAVING d < '2012-01-31' AND d > '2012-01-01'`.

The correct query would be as follow :

```
SET @date = '2012-01-01';
SELECT @date := date_add(@date, interval 1 day) as d
FROM t
WHERE date_add(@date, interval 1 day) < '2012-01-31'
ORDER BY d
LIMIT 30;
```

Note that a `HAVING` clause should be used with aggregate functions, and that using LIMIT without an `ORDER BY` clause might give you results in an incorrect order.

Comment: +1 good explanation at first glance i have missed the fact for the having clause that it will again compute the expression